# Why is the value of 1 outputted for every row in sales rank?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know to rank it by sales I can just remove the partition; but what is the partition function doing that would cause all values of rank to be outputted as 1?

```
select
trunc(sales_date,'MON') as sales_month,
sum(sales_amount) as Monthly_Sales,
rank() over (partition by trunc (sales_date,'MON') order by sum(sales_amount) desc) as Sales_Rank
from s
group by trunc(sales_date,'MON')
order by 1;


SALES_MON MONTHLY_SALES SALES_RANK
--------- ------------- ----------
01-JAN-15          5600          1
01-FEB-15         50880          1
01-MAR-15        126120          1
01-APR-15        118320          1
01-MAY-15          2280          1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partition by creates Group for your data in the query. In your query, you have partitioned i.e. Grouped your data by Month for Ranks. So this is showing as 1 for each row and you already grouped your data.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one record in each month.  You are starting the ranking enumeration with each month, so you get exactly "1" for each rank.

That is how `partition by` works.  It restarts the enumeration.